# Questioning Involving Sum of Two Squares Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

I have the following algebraic number theory question that is giving me trouble.

The question: Suppose that $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $xy = z^2 + 1$. Prove that there exist $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

(i) $x = a^{2} + b^{2}$

(ii) $y = c^{2} + d^{2}$

(iii) $z = ac + bd$

---

My thoughts:

To me the largest issue is verifying (iii). If (i), (ii) are satisfied this amounts to saying that $x = N(a+bi)$ and $y = N(c + di)$. Using the multiplicativity of the Norm over the Gaussian integers you can push things around and get that
$$
N(a+bi)N(c+di) = N( (ac + bd) +(ad - bc)i).
$$
So to me this problem is saying find $a, b, c, d$ such that $x = N(a+bi)$, $y=N(c + di)$ and the $\mathbb{Z}$-sublattice of the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ generated by $a+bi$ and $c+di$ is the entire Gaussians, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{Z} (a+bi) + \mathbb{Z} (c+di) = \mathbb{Z} 1 + \mathbb{Z} i = \mathbb{Z}[i]
$$
Indeed $ad - bc = +/- 1$ exactly when we have the above equality of lattices and in either case we deduce
$$
z^{2} + 1 = N( (ac + bd) +(ad - bc)i) = (ac+bd)^{2} + (ad-bc)^{2} = (ac + bd)^{2} + 1
$$
giving us condition (iii).

However, I have no idea how to determine when the containment
$$
\mathbb{Z} (a+bi) + \mathbb{Z} (c+di) \subseteq \mathbb{Z} 1 + \mathbb{Z} i = \mathbb{Z}[i]
$$
is actually an equality. Beyond taking a determinant which requires more knowledge of $a,b,c,d$ than I think I have.

Comment: Something that jumps out to me is that, working over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, you can factor the RHS of your equation.

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Bhaskar.pdf), specifically Theorem 3.6, 3.7, 3.10. Note that this does not use the complicated notation you use in your attempt (which I don't understand)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity directly? The fact that the product $xy$ can be represented as a sum of two squares with one of those two squares being $1$ implies that some combination of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ must exist such that $ad-bc = 1$ and hence $ac+bd=z$.

Comment: Eric I am not sure I follow. Can you give more detail? Seems nice if true.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently posting a question causes you to find an answer immediately. Here it is:

Fact 1: In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we have $z^{2} + 1 = (z+i)(z-i)$. If $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime dividing $z+i$, then $p$ divides $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ which is impossible. Similarly, $p$ doesn't divide $z-i$.

By Fact 1, $p$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$: since $z+i, z-i$ are co-prime, if $p$ were irreducible it would have to divide $z+i$ or $z-i$ which it cannot by Fact 1.

So $p = (e+fi)(g + hi)$ has a factorization into non-units. Taking norms we see that $p^{2} = (e^{2} + f^{2})(g^{2} + h^{2}).$ Since the non-units in the Gaussians are exactly those whose Norm is not $1$, we see that $p = e^{2} + f^{2}$ and we have a factorization $p = (e+fi)(e-fi).$ And $e+fi, e-fi$ are both irreducible since their norm is a prime number.

Furthermore, $e+fi$ and $e-fi$ cannot both divide $z+i$ and cannot both divide $z-i$ lest $p$ divide $z+i$ or $z-i$. See Fact 1.

Summary: if $p_{j}$ divides $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ then there exist $a_{j}, b_{j} \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that: (1) $p_{j} = N(a_{j} + b_{j} i)$ ; (2) $a_{j} + b_{j} i $ and $a_{j} - b_{j} i$ are irreducible; $a_{j} + b_{j}i$ divides $z+i$ but not $z-i$; $a_{j} - b_{j}i$ divides $z-i$ but not $z+i$.

Clearly the same is true for primes dividing $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Now let $x = \prod p_{i}^{n_{i}} $ and $y = \prod q_{t}^{m_{t}}$ be prime factorizations in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then by the summary we can find collections $a_{j}, b_{j}, c_{t}, d_{t}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$-integers such that: (1) $x = \prod N((a_{j} + b_{j}i)^{n_{j}})$; (2) $y = \prod N((c_{t} + d_{t}i)^{m_{t}})$; (3) $z+i = \prod (a_{j} + b_{j}i)^{n_{j}} \prod (c_{t} + d_{t}i)^{m_{t}}$ ; (4) $z-i = \prod (a_{j} - b_{j}i)^{n_{j}} \prod (c_{t} - d_{t}i)^{m_{t}}$.

Now write $\prod(a_{j} + b_{j}i)^{n_{j}})$ as $a - bi$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Similarly write $\prod(c_{t} + d_{t}i)^{m_{t}}$ as $c + di$ for $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we see that:
$$ (i) x = N(a-bi) = a^{2} + b^{2} (\text{ this is } (1))$$
$$ (ii) y = N(c+di) = c^{2} + d^{2} (\text{this is } (2))$$.

Moreover (3) implies that $z+i= (a-bi)(c+di) = (ac + bd) + (ad - bc)i$. That is we have
$$ (iii) z = ac+bd$$.

Answer (score 0):

Following on to my comment, as this would be too long for just a comment.

We have $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which is important because zeros would not be fun.

$z^2+1$ is obviously the sum of two squares (STS). If it can be factored as $xy$, then there is some factorization for which both $x$ and $y$ are also STS. There may be factorizations in which $x$ and $y$ are not STS, but that can only be true if a factorization into two STS is also available. Hence (i) and (ii) are true.

The Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity says that if a number is the product of two STS, then it can be expressed as (at least) two different STS:

$$xy = (a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac+bd)^2 + (ad-bc)^2 = (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2$$

Because $xy$ is the product of two STS, and $z^2+1$ is a representation of $xy$, there *must* be an arrangement where $z^2 = ac+bd$ and $ad-bc = 1$. Obviously, $ac+bd \ne 1$ as we have no zeros. And we can choose $ac+bd$ or $ad+bc$ WLOG, showing (iii) to be true.

Comment: Paragraph 2: It is not obvious to me that if $\alpha$ is a sum of two squares and $\alpha = \beta \gamma$ then $\beta$, $\gamma$ are also sum of two squares. For instance take $\alpha$ to be a $p^{2}$ for $p \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 4$ and $\alpha$, $\gamma = p$. By the sum of two squares $p^{2}$ is the sum of two squares whereas $p$ is not. Paragraph 3: I don't understand why the ``must'' part means this choice of $a,b,c,d$ also respects the factorization you have picked. Or even why the must is there.

Comment: Para 2: If $\alpha = p^2$, then it is *not* the product of two nontrivial STS. We could factor it as $x=p^2, y=1$, but that would require a zero among $c,d$, as $1=1^2+0^2$ is the only way to express $1$ as STS. The STS theorem provides that iff a STS can be factored non-trivially, there must exist a factorization into two STS. Consider, for instance, $245$. You *can* factor it as $7\cdot 35$, but you can also factor is as $5 \cdot 49$, which is two STS.

Comment: Para 3: The BF identity is technically a biconditional. The fact that $z^2+1$ is the product of two STS means that the expression as $z^2+1^2$ is one of the possible expressions on the RHS. That is, because it *can* be expressed this way, $1$ *must* be $ad-bc$ (WLOG) for some $a,b,c,d$ that give $z=ac+bd$. That is, existence implies satisfaction of the identity. If you have $a,b,c,d$ such that neither $ad-bc$ nor $ac-bd$ is $1$, the number *cannot be* $z^2+1^2$.